# Is GZIP algorithm platform independent

Tags: java, compression, gzip

Is there a way to make sure once I compress a file using a library in Java. I can uncompress the file in any other language which supports GZIP libraries.
I can see that GZIP is backed by Data format spec https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952

But did not see any more resources to verify platform independence of GZIP

Comment: Basically you have to test on your target platforms to make sure it works.  I don't know of any reason why Gzip would not be platform independent.

Comment: RFC 1952 *is* the 'resource to verify platform independence'. You don't need any others.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The gzip format is entirely platform independent.

Answer (score 1):

The GZIP format is platform independent.  It defines the format as a sequence of octets, and is independent of platform or network hardware byte ordering issues.  You can confirm this for yourself by reading the spec carefully.

Any tool that implements the GZIP specification *correctly*<sup>1</sup> should handle a GZIP file created by any other (spec compliant) tool on any other platform.

There are a couple of minor caveats:

1. A GZIP file can optionally encode the original (source) file name.  The spec says that the optional filename should consist of ISO 8859-1 characters.  This is a limitation if either the source filename contains characters that do not map to ISO 8859-1, OR if the system where you are decoding cannot map all ISO 8859-1 characters to the character set used for filenames.
2. A GZIP file can optionally contain a modification timestamp, represented as a offset from "00:00:00 GMT, Jan. 1, 1970"<sup>2</sup>.  As the spec notes, this can be problematic on platforms where GMT / UTC time is not available; e.g. MS-DOS.

The tools that create and read GZIP files should be able to cope with this.  For example, the GNU gzip tools shipped as standard on Linux distros have a `--no-name` option that tells the commands to not save or restore the original filename and timestamp.

---

<sup>1 - All bets are off for tools that are incorrect implementations of the spec.  But you are unlikely to find such a tool in the wild.</sup>

<sup>2 - The spec says GMT, not UTC.  I am just quoting what it says.</sup>